# мой исходник не верен,помогите

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая считывает целое положительное число n, , n \in [1; , 9]n,n∈[1;9] и выводит значение числа n+\overline{nn}+\overline{nnn}n+
nn
+
nnn
.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаётся одно целое положительное число n, , n \in [1; , 9]n,n∈[1;9].

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести число n+\overline{nn}+\overline{nnn}n+
nn
+
nnn
.

Примечание. Для первого теста 1 + 11 + 111 = 1231+11+111=123.

Sample Input 1:

1
Sample Output 1:

123

```
a = int(input())
print(a + (10*a + 1) + (100*a + 10*a  +2))
```

И ДА ЗНАЮ ЧТО ЭТО ПРИМИТИВНЫЙ ПУТЬ!!! НО МНЕ НАДО РЕШАТЬ ИМЕННО ТАК!!!

Comment: Зачем же кричать?

Comment: Ну я хочу решить эту задачу))

Comment: Как же это Вам поможет? Поясните.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = int(input())
aa = 10*a + a
aaa = 100*a + aa
print(a + aa + aaa)
```

Comment: благодарю вам !!!

Comment: @Егор Когда участник [получает хороший ответ на свой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), он может отметить его как верный – «принять». После принятия ответа слева от него появляется галочка зелёного цвета.

Comment: я в курсе) просто когда я нажал система показал тайминг 6мин))) я уже отметил)))

Answer (score 1):

Буду использовать обозначения, как в предыдущем ответе

```
a=input()
aaa=str(a)+str(a)+str(a) #писать str не обязательно - я написал просто чтобы показать, что складываются строки 
aa=aaa[0:-1]

print(int(a)+int(aa)+int(aaa))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
print(n * 123)
```